# Calculate centroid in PCA

Tags: r, pca

If I understand correctly in order to calculate a centroid in PCA I can calculate the mean of X points and Y points (e.g., PC1 and PC2).

When I run a simple PCA (code below) I don’t get the centroid of each group (species). Unfortunately, I do not know how to continue from this point as I am new in R. Therefore, how can I calculate the centroid of each group and plot it?

```
require(ggplot2)
pca <- prcomp(iris[,-5])
dataset = data.frame(species = iris[,"Species"], pca = pca$x)
mx <- mean(dataset$pca.PC1)
my <- mean(dataset$pca.PC2)
ggplot(dataset) + 
  geom_point(aes(pca.PC1, pca.PC2, colour = species, shape = species), 
             size = 4) + 
  geom_point(aes(mx,my), size = 7)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please see this link, i think it can answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208909/how-to-calculate-centroids-in-pca